# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Landroidx/room/testing/MigrationTestHelper;

Tags: android, android-room, android-unit-testing

I got following error when i executed my unit test.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Landroidx/room/testing/MigrationTestHelper;

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.getSortedDeclaredFields(TestClass.java:77)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.scanAnnotatedMembers(TestClass.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.createTestClass(ParentRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

My test codes.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MigrationTest {


    private val migrations = arrayOf(
            Composition.MIGRATION_1_2, BriefComposition.MIGRATION_1_2)

    @Rule
    val helper: MigrationTestHelper = MigrationTestHelper(
            InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
            HomePageDatabase::class.java.canonicalName,
            FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory()
    )

    @Test
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun migrateAll() {
        // Create earliest version of the database.
        helper.createDatabase(HomePageDatabase.DB_NAME, 1).apply {
            close()
        }
        // Open latest version of the database. Room will validate the schema
        // once all migrations execute.
        Room.databaseBuilder(
                InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext,
                HomePageDatabase::class.java,
                HomePageDatabase.DB_NAME
        ).addMigrations(*migrations)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build().apply {
                    openHelper.writableDatabase
                    close()
                }
    }
}
```

What's more `androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.5` is added to my build.gradle as `androidTestImplementation`, but i have no ideas why this problem happened

Comment: [The Room guide](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions) shows `testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.5"`.  Are you using `androidTestImplementation`?

Comment: @BobSnyder yes, because there are some dependent classes belong to androidx, eg:```androidx.room.Room``` ```androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper```